# How to refer current class using decltype in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, static-methods, decltype

When I declare a class static method, is it possible to refer current class using `decltype` (or in any other similar style)? For example,

```
class
AAA
{
    static AAA const make();
};
```

I am trying to make something like this.

```
class
AAA
{
    static decltype(*this) const make();  // Not working because there's no `this`.
};
```

The `*this` is used to describe what I want to do. I want to know some `decltype()` expression which can be resolved to `AAA`.

If it's possible how can I do that?

Comment: I don't know why you want to trade the clear and concise form of `static AAA const make()` for the indirect `static decltype(*this) const make()`. Readability is king, and being explicit about your types helps your readers a lot.

Comment: Is the idea behind this to add a `make` function to a whole hierarchy of classes in a particular "smart" way? That'd be a case for the curiously recurring template parameter pattern. If this is only for one class, I don't understand the need to derive the return type, `AAA` would do fine (but then, I don't understand what's wrong with calling the constructor, either).

Comment: I don't have specific instance of use-case. I suddenly am curious on this, and if this is possible, I think maybe I can figure out some interesting applications later. I don't claim any goodness of badness of idea in this question. I also thought this wouldn't that much useful, but this question was bugging me for a long time, so I decided to ask this.

Answer (score 5):

In C++1y you could do this:

```
class
AAA
{
public:
    static auto make()
    {
        return AAA();
    }
};

int main()
{
    AAA aaa = AAA::make();
}
```

This is not legal in C++11 as you need to specify a return type for `make()`.  In C++98/03/11 you can:

```
class
AAA
{
public:
    typedef AAA Self;

    static Self make()
    {
        return AAA();
    }
};
```

That is low-tech, but very readable.

`<aside>`

You should avoid returning const-qualified types by value.  This inhibits efficient move semantics.  If you want to avoid assigning to rvalues, then create an assignment operator qualified with `&`.

`</aside>`

Answer (score 0):

<s>You could perhaps do something like this:</s>

```
#include<iostream>

class AAA
{
   int _i;

   public:
   AAA(int i): _i(i) {}

   static auto make(int i) -> typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type
   {
      return {i};
   }

   void print()
   {
      std::cout << _i << std::endl;
   }
};

int main()
{
    AAA aaa = AAA::make(1);
    aaa.print();
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles on GCC 4.7.2 at least :)

---

EDIT 26/11-13: The above code is not legal c++, even though it compiles with gcc, it does not with clang or icpc. My apologies.

Comment: User hvd already made a similar suggestion (now deleted), but it's not allowed: [expr.prim.general]/3 about the expression `this`: "It shall not appear before the optional *cv-qualifier-seq* and it shall not appear within the declaration of a static member function"

Comment: @DyP: I suspected that might have been the case. Thanks, post updated.

Answer (score 0):

Just invented a way using member pointers, and it seems to work:
https://godbolt.org/z/v-g5z0

```
    #define self_test(name) \
    void dummy__##name(void) {} \
    template  static T type__##name( void (T::*func)(void) ) { return T(); } \
    typedef decltype(type__##name(&dummy__##name)) self__##name; \
    static void test( void ) { self__##name::print(); }

    struct T1 {
      self_test(X);
      static void print() { printf( "this is T1\n" ); }
    };

    struct T2 {
      self_test(X);
      static void print() { printf( "this is T2\n" ); }
    };

    int main() {
      T1::test();
      T2::test();
    }
```

This is not perfect either, it requires -fpermissive to compile with gcc,
but at least gcc/VS/Intel all compile it and it works.
Also in fact gcc/mingw doesn't even require -fpermissive for this.