# decltype(*this) equivalent outside function body

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

Is it possible to write a trait, which results the type of the class it is used in? How to implement get_class in the example below?

```
class Foo {
    typedef get_class::type type; // type = Foo now
};
```

Note: I have to write a macro, which expands in the class body, used for multiple classes, so I cannot simply write 'typedef Foo type;'

Use case:

I have a reflectable(...) macro which generates infrastructure to iterate over members, visit them and look them up using their names:

```
class Foo 
{
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const Foo&);
    reflectable(
         (int) bar,
         (double) baz
    )
}
```

reflectable(...) should be a macro so I can get the types and member names separately as strings to build maps for the lookup.

I would like all reflectable class to be streamable, but if I put my reflectable() macro to private section, I have to add the friend declaration to the class. I would like to move it to the macro as:

```
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const get_class::type&);
```

Comment: What's your use-case for this? I don't see it.

Comment: Well, you can always accept enclosing type name as a macro parameter. Also some coding standards require each class to declare a class type alias member.

Comment: If it is acceptable in your case, you can write a helper template class which will `typedef` it's template parameter and you will neet to derive `Foo` from `Helper<Foo>`.

Comment: @DeiDei I have updated the question with my use case.

Comment: @k.v. I don't know Foo in the macro, so I cannot instantiate the Helper class.

Comment: @VTT Yes, both solution is possible, but it would need redundant code in the user class which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Suggestion: use Boost.Fusion adapted sequences to iterate over members. It will save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to refer current class using decltype in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203640/how-to-refer-current-class-using-decltype-in-c11)

Comment: @cpplearner That question is a near-dupe, but there are not satisfying answers (no accepted answer too). Perhaps the OP should offer a bounty on that question, instead of asking again.

Comment: @cpplearner, yes, the question seems to be a duplicate first, but if you consider the use case - I have added, and - would like to solve, it is not an exact duplicate.

Comment: Just have your macro befriend some class like `reflectable_access`, then that class can access the private stuff defined by your macro and expose it publicly.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks! It solves my problem completely!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, but I'm pretty sure that in standard C++ there is no way around you having to pass in the class name to the macro one way or another.
For some failed attempts, see the end of this answer.

---

That said, I think your best bet is to slightly change your design. Instead of

```
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const get_class::type&);
```

provide a **public** member function

```
void stream_to (std::ostream &) const {
  // Implementation
}
```

together with a free function template

```
template<typename T, typename std:: enable_if<has_stream_to<T>::value>::type * = nullptr>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream & s, T const & t) {
  t.stream_to(s);
  return s;
}
```

in your libraries/programs namespace. (Note: I'll add the trait `has_stream_to` later, for the impatient search for "detect member function" within C++ tag)

---

Approaches that **don't** work:

- Use a pointer to member function, extract the class type with a template function. Reason: `&foo` inside of a class with a member function `foo` won't give a member function pointer to `foo`. The syntax is *required* (by the standard) to be `&C::foo` (where `C` is the class name...).
- Use a pointer to data member, extract the class type with a template function. Same reason as above.
- Use a dedicated member function that returns `*this`, deduce the return type to get the class type. Reason: Need an instance to call this function on.
- Use a pointer to a static member function. Reason: Such pointers are same as pointers to free functions, the class name cannot be deduced from them.
- Use the `this` pointer in a member initialisation. Reason: type of member needs to encode class type somehow, but `auto` is not allowed for non static data members.

Comment: @skypjack Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: Compiles with G++ 5.4, but MSVC and clang complains: 'this' cannot be used in a static member function declaration

Comment: I have been using a similar approach for some time now, and it works pretty fine (under G++). Only one note, both the `get_type()` function and the `type` declaration should be private, in case the OP is using inheritance with several classes deducing their type

Comment: Compiles fine though ... but this is most likely a gcc bug.

Comment: I deleted the answer for that code isn't valid. You should rather remove it from your answer.

Comment: @skypjack I did. It indeed isn't valid. Any idea whether this is already submitted as bug report to GCC?

Comment: @DanielJour I've already seen it, so I'd say yes. Meanwhile I resumed my answer and added a slightly modified version that compiles and is also valid code.

Comment: Dear down voter, please explain how I can improve my answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but note that your `stream_to` still has to be public for the detection to work. Also, that `final` is ill-formed on a non-virtual member function.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: I have to write a macro, which expands in the class body, used for multiple classes, so I cannot simply write 'typedef Foo type;'

If you can expand the macro when declaring the class instead of in the class body, something like this could work:

```
#include<type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct Type {
    using type = T;
};

#define struct_with_type(S) struct S: Type<S>

struct_with_type(Foo) {};

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<Foo::type, Foo>::value, "!");
}
```

---

Note that the example proposed with my previous answer isn't valid code:

```
struct Foo {
    static constexpr auto get_type() -> std::decay_t<decltype(*this)>;
    using type = decltype(get_type());
};
```

It compiles only with GCC because of a bug of that compiler.
Something I wouldn't use in a production code.

That being said, if you like it, the following compiles and it's something close to that solution:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<utility>

#define add_type() constexpr auto type() -> std::decay_t<decltype(*this)>;

template<typename T>
using get_type = decltype(std::declval<T>().type());

struct Foo {
    add_type();
};

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<get_type<Foo>, Foo>::value, "!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I cannot use your last code snippet, I would need get_type inside the macro, so I cannot instantiate it with Foo. On the other hand the struct_with_type macro might work, limits additional inheritence  though.

Comment: @simon You can easily extend the macro to support inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a really nice solution, but it might do the trick for you on simple functions. I have not extended it so far for templates and other stuff such as variadic functions:

```
#define FUNCTION_DECL(R, N, ...) \
        R N(__VA_ARGS__);

#define DEFINE_FRIEND_OPERATOR(CLASS_NAME, MEMBERS)                       \
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, CLASS_NAME const& f) \
    {                                                                     \
        std::cout << #CLASS_NAME << ':' << std::endl;                     \
        MEMBERS                                                           \
        return s;                                                         \
    }

#define S_(X) #X
#define S(X) S_(X)

#define STREAM_FUNCTION(R, N, ...) \
    s << "  " #R " " #N S((__VA_ARGS__)) << std::endl;
```

I do not see any portable way of having the class name other than passing it to the macro, thus the type trait skipped.

You could now place above macros into some appropriate header (and find better/more suitable names...), which would be included for each class. There, you'd have:

```
class Foo
{
#define FOO_MEMBERS                    \
        MEMBER(int, f0, int, int, int) \
        MEMBER(double, f1, double)     \
        MEMBER(void, f2, char const)

public:
#ifdef MEMBER
#undef MEMBER
#endif
#define MEMBER FUNCTION_DECL
    FOO_MEMBERS
#undef MEMBER

private:
#define MEMBER STREAM_FUNCTION
    DEFINE_FRIEND_OPERATOR(Foo, FOO_MEMBERS)
#undef MEMBER
};
```

For the map entries, you'd have similar macros, generating an initialiser list in the constructor such as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250123/what-would-a-stdmap-extended-initializer-list-look-like).

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, this sounds like an XY problem. Instead, add a layer of indirection:

```
class Foo 
{
    friend class reflectable_access;
    reflectable(
         (int) bar,
         (double) baz
    )
};
```

Now `reflectable_access` can access the things added by your `reflectable` macro and expose them to others requiring access to them.

Comment: If it's a template class I can move the friend declaration to the macro and instantiate it where I want to use.